# Summing values in a dataframe over row labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, sum, label

i have a dataframe of the following form

```
    index    FACTOR1     FACTOR2    FACTOR3
0   ECON1   -0.068475   -0.000000   -0.000000
1   ECON2   0.000000    0.056963    0.000000
2   ECON2   0.000000    0.000000    0.041488
3   FOOD1   0.018582    0.000000    0.000000
4   FOOD2   -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.044363
5   FOOD3   -0.000000   -0.057993   -0.000000
6   ENV1    -0.045415   -0.000000   -0.000000
7   ENV2    0.000000    0.000000    0.044539
8   HEA1    -0.000000   -0.069631   -0.000000
9   HEA2    -0.000000   -0.000000   -0.026604
10  HEA3    0.028243    0.000000    0.000000
11  PERS1   0.000000    0.000000    0.085750
12  PERS2   0.000000    0.017831    0.000000
13  PERS3   0.069533    0.000000    0.000000
14  COM1    -0.025689   -0.000000   -0.000000
15  COM2    -0.029949   -0.000000   -0.000000
16  POL1    -0.000000   -0.061723   -0.000000
17  POL2    0.059108    0.000000    0.000000
```

My aim is to sum the values of columns `Factor 1`, `Factor 2` and `Factor 3` over each row label. What I call label is for instance `ECON` which aggregate `ECON1`, `ECON2` and `ECON3`. Similarly, `FOOD` is another label and contains `FOOD1`, `FOOD2` and `FOOD3`.

I was thinking to create an array of string in the following form:

`labels=['ECON', 'FOOD', 'ENV', 'HEA', 'PERS', 'COM', 'POL']` and loop over all corresponding `labels`, flatten their values and sum them. The logic would be as follows:

```
summation=[]
for i in range(labels):
    summation[i,:]=np.sum(xxxx)
```

However, i am not sure how to process this in a loop since at each label i have a matrix of values.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can `extract` the group names and `sum`:

```
print (df.assign(group=df["index"].str.extract("([A-Z]+)"))
         .groupby("group").sum())
```

Or using your list of labels:

```
labels=['ECON', 'FOOD', 'ENV', 'HEA', 'PERS', 'COM', 'POL']

print (df.assign(group=df["index"].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(labels)})"))
         .groupby("group").sum())
```

Result:

```
        FACTOR1   FACTOR2   FACTOR3
group                              
COM   -0.055638  0.000000  0.000000
ECON  -0.068475  0.056963  0.041488
ENV   -0.045415  0.000000  0.044539
FOOD   0.018582 -0.057993 -0.044363
HEA    0.028243 -0.069631 -0.026604
PERS   0.069533  0.017831  0.085750
POL    0.059108 -0.061723  0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer which works great if we decide to sum by `labels` only. However, i was looking to double sum by `labels` and by `Factor` which means one value for each `label`. That's why i was suggesting to maybe flatten the values before summing them.

Comment: Just add an additional `sum(1)` at the end @bravopapa .

Comment: True. I should sum over columns . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested answer that completes the previous answer from Henry

```
labels=['ECON', 'FOOD', 'ENV', 'HEA', 'PERS', 'COM', 'POL']

AugmentedMatrix=ReadyMatrix.assign(group=ReadyMatrix["index"].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(labels)})"))             

summation=np.zeros(( len(labels) , 1 ))
for i in range(len(labels)):
    print(labels[i])                               
    temp=AugmentedMatrix.loc[AugmentedMatrix['group']==labels[i], ['FACTOR1', 'FACTOR2', 'FACTOR3']].values
    summation[i]=np.sum(temp) 
print(summation)
```